# What to do with unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I have some questions on MathSE that does not have actually any answer. What is the best to do other than bounty ? Asking the same question for a second time or trying to edit the question ?

Comment: Certainly the worst thing you can do is ask the same question a second time.  The best thing to do depends on the circumstances of your unanswered question.  Certainly if you have improvements to make (see [How to ask](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and related Help topics on the main site), go ahead and make them (on the theory that it cannot hurt).  Consider improving the tags and title as well as the body of the Question.

Comment: Some questions are unanswered because they are too complicated to understand, not in a field of interest of most users, etc.  So they remain unanswered forever...  Re-asking them, or offering a bounty won't help.  So: first ask yourself if your question falls into this category.